# Find specific translation

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I have a breadcrumb named "Home" in my checkout.xml. For some reason, at some point, I have translated this to something that I don't want it to be translated to anymore.

However, no matter how much I look in my Mage_Core.csv and Mage_Checkout.csv and, I can't find that specific translation. I have tried overwriting it as well and searching in all files on my computer for the translation - no luck..

Can someone please help me figure out where to find it and remove it again?

Thanks already!

Comment: Perhaps the translation is in the database instead?

Comment: Where would that be? :-)

Comment: In core_translate (as David said in the answer)

Comment: You can use my TranslationHints extension to determine the source of translations https://github.com/schmengler/TranslationHints

Answer (score 4):

Translations can be in a couple of places.

- Translations files under locale. Have a look under `app/locale/*_*/File.csv` where `*_*` is the right code,
- Theme locale files. Have a look under `app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/*_*/translate.csv` where `*_*` is the right code,
- Database entries. Have a look in the table `core_translate`.

For the file section you can either use a find in files search in your favorite IDE or a grep command.

This should help you find the file and translation.

Comment: Thank you! Thought I had looked into all files already, but further searching made me find the same string in both Mage_adminhtml.csv and Mage_Cms.csv. Can I force the breadcrumb to overwrite these, or should I simply change the entry in all files?

Comment: @user2806026 I would not change the core files like that what I would suggest is a locale file in your theme. Then in there you can simply add what translation changes your theme requires. Changing the core files is bad practice as these changes will be lost during the next upgrade you perform.

Comment: Thanks! But a mage_checkout.csv-file in my theme just doesnt seem to be able to overwrite translations that exist in other .csv-files already..

Comment: You can prepend the translations with the module which should help translation priority. `"Mage_Checkout:Original Text","New Text"` should do it for you.

Comment: The theme translation file is always named **translate.csv**. David was referring to the language code with `*_*` (like `en_US`)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try, is by searching via the terminal (or whatever you use on your OS):

1. Navigate to the Magento installation directory
2. Use the grep command to search for the string:

   grep -r --color "STRING" PATH/

For example:

```
grep -r --color "Home" app/
```